# Vectorize a for loop with multiple conditions that loops through dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, vectorization

I have a large dataset of 7 million rows and I am trying to go through each row of the data frame and change the value in a column based on a set of conditions.

This is taking a lot of time and I am wondering if it is possible to vectorize the process or if there are a more efficient and faster way of doing it. I am using R code

My code is below:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(tttotalCam2020)){
  viewTime <- tttotalCam2020[row, "DAY_DATE"]
  termCode <- tttotalCam2020[row, "TERM_CODE"]
  
  if(termCode=='SP1'){
    if(viewTime <= as.POSIXct("2020/01/31")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Early'
    }else if(as.POSIXct("2020/02/1") >= viewTime & viewTime <= as.POSIXct("2020/03/8")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Mid'
    }else{
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Late'
    }
  }else if(termCode=='SP2'){
    if(viewTime <=as.POSIXct("2020/03/31")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Early'
    }else if(as.POSIXct("2020/04/1")>=viewTime & viewTime <=as.POSIXct("2020/06/5")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Mid'
    }else{
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Late'
    }
  }else {
    if(viewTime <=as.POSIXct("2020/04/24")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Early'
    }else if(as.POSIXct("2020/04/25")>=viewTime & viewTime <=as.POSIXct("2020/05/31")){
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Mid'
    }else{
      tttotalCam2020[row,'COURSE_PERIOD']='Late'
    }
```

Comment: `dplyr::case_when()` is vectorized and would make for readable code. For faster transformation `data.table` package offers solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to help if you can share example data that we can test on.

A `dplyr::case_when` solution could look like this:

```
library(dplyr)

tttotalCam2020 %>%
  mutate(COURSE_PERIOD = case_when(
    termCode == "SP1" & viewtime <= as.POSIXct("2020/01/31") ~ "Early",
    termCode == "SP1" & viewtime <= as.POSIXct("2020/03/08") ~ "Mid",
    # etc.
  ))
```

If you have a lot of different `termCodes`, it might be better to take advantage of the repeated structure and do something like this, where you put all the dates in one table, join it to your main data, and then you can use cleaner code to get your result. That should be very fast, since joins are very efficient and then you just have one vectorized calculation to do.

```
library(lubridate)

lookup_table <- tribble(
  ~termCode, ~Early, ~Mid,
  "SP1", 20200131, 20200308,
  "SP2", 20200331, 20200605,
  "SP3", 20200424, 20200531) %>%
  mutate(across(Early:Mid, ymd))  #lubridate::ymd

tttotalCam2020 %>%
  left_join(lookup_table) %>%
  mutate(COURSE_PERIOD = case_when(
    viewTime <= Early ~ "Early",
    viewTime <= Mid ~ "Mid",
    TRUE ~ "Late"
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `mapply()` function.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mapply

With `mapply()` you can define a function with several input values (e.g. conditions in columns) and run it without requiring a for-loop.